# Exeption trying to connect to Azure database from my C# / .NET 8 application

Tags: c#, database, azure, .net-8.0

I'm trying to connect to an Azure database from my .NET 8 application.

The code is:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "{myname}.database.windows.net";
builder.UserID = "{my userID}";
builder.Password = "{my psw}";
builder.InitialCatalog = "{my catalog}";

try
{
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
   connection.Open();
}
```

When I try to launch the connection, I get the exception

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager' threw an exception

on calling `connection.Open();`

I can't find anything about this issue anywhere, can someone help me?

Comment: Can you connect to database with different method like SSMS? If you can connect to database different method you can try to update Nuget packages and check your configuration again. If you can't connect to database with different method you have to check your Azure configuration (Firewall etc.).

Comment: Did you check the full stacktrace? I would expect an inner exception with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few Steps that you can follow:

1. Get the full connection string and try connecting instead of manually building using Connection builder.
2. Sometimes we also need to add specfic IP address when setting up a SQL Server on Azure. You can try adding you system ip address.
3. Try connecting it by SSMS(As said in comments).

If nothing works then just let us know the exception message.

Comment: Azure SQL Firewall is most likely the issue.

Comment: Thank you all guys for the help. The solution was pretty easy, the IP on Azure's Firewall was wrong and was enough to update it.